# local database for each user in application

Tags: c#, winforms

In my c# windows application, I had a requirement to create a local database where the c# application's set up is installed. The data of login user through that 
computer must be stored in that local database.There is a sqldatabase which consist of all user's data.I need to import single user's data to their local machine database(MS Access) from sqlserver database..How can I fulfill my requirement?

Comment: You can use compact database edition of sql server in your windows application.so all the data will be stored in that database

Comment: Keep in-file database file in user's local folder

Comment: You can use Microsoft Access Database.

Answer (score 1):

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) works well for this and has plenty of documentation and .NET wrapper libraries to help get you up and running quickly.